# Parsing a Youtube API Date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, date, youtube

Youtube's API returns a JSON object with an array of videos. Each video object has a published date formatted like "2012-01-11T20:49:59.415Z".  If I initialize a Javascript Date object using the code below, the object returns "Invalid Date".

```
var dt = new Date( "2012-01-11T20:49:59.415Z" );
```

I'm using this on iOS/mobile Safari, if that makes a difference.

Any suggestions or ideas on how to create a valid object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution at http://zetafleet.com/blog/javascript-dateparse-for-iso-8601.  It looks like the date is in a format called 'ISO 8601.'  On earlier browsers (Safari 4, Chrome 4, IE 6-8), ISO 8601 is not supported, so Date.parse doesn't work.  The code referenced from the linked blog post extends the current Date class to support ISO 8601.

Answer (score 4):

Try using JavaScript's [`Date.parse(string)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) and the [`Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) which takes the number of milliseconds since the epoch.  The "parse" function should accept a valid ISO8601 date on any browser.

For example:

```
var d = new Date(Date.parse("2012-01-11T20:49:59.415Z"));
d.toString(); // => Wed Jan 11 2012 15:49:59 GMT-0500 (EST)
d.getTime(); // => 1326314999415
```

Comment: This doesn't work in older browsers.  I'm testing this on iOS 4.2.1 and iOS 5.0.1. iOS 4 fails, while iOS 5 works.

Answer (score 3):

```
var dt = "2012-01-11T20:49:59.415Z".replace("T"," ").replace(/\..+/g,"")
dt = new Date( dt );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a portion of the date (eg. if you don't care about the time or time zone) you can just strip that portion of the date string off.

Comment: I'm trying to generate a relative date, like "21 days ago" by pulling the milliseconds from the Date object.

Comment: That's easy when you finish with the rendering of the date through the ISO 8601 script. Make a global new date parse it to ISO 8601 date object and then subtract the "posted date" from the "current date"...

Answer (score 0):

This page has code that parses youtube (ISO 8601) dates into a date object:

http://webcloud.se/log/JavaScript-and-ISO-8601/

[Archive.org backup of same](https://web.archive.org/web/20130115191531/http://webcloud.se/log/JavaScript-and-ISO-8601/)

It work for me, though I haven't tested it very much.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20130115191531/http://webcloud.se/log/JavaScript-and-ISO-8601/