# Angular JS - YouTube timestamp to UNIX

Tags: angularjs, youtube-api, unix-timestamp, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to create an angular filter that converts my UNIX timestamp that I get from a datetimepicker to the YouTube formatted date and vice versa. I've searched everywhere but all I could find is a PHP function...  Can someone provide assistance with this?

UNIX: 1440072453
YouTube: 2015-01-08T11:29:40.000Z

Answer (score 0):

Example :

```
var d = new Date(Date.parse("2012-01-11T20:49:59.415Z"));
d.toString(); // => Wed Jan 11 2012 15:49:59 GMT-0500 (EST)
d.getTime(); // => 1326314999415
```

From [Parsing a Youtube API Date in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827213/parsing-a-youtube-api-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm, thanks.  What about go back from the long string to UNIX?